# Why /usr/include/linux/stddef.h is empty?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

This header file shall define `NULL` or `size_t` and other macros, but I find that `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h` is empty? Why?

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stddef_8h_source.html

Comment: Nominally, you include `/usr/include/stddef.h` when you write `#include <stddef.h>`.  What that does is up to the implementation.  Maybe there's nothing needed in the `linux/stddef.h` header — the standard one, or a header included from another sub-directory, contains all that's necessary.

Answer (score 15):

The actual location of the headers is implementation defined. What you look at is not the typical `<stddef.h>` included by gcc. You can find out exactly where it's located on your system with:

```
gcc -E - <<<'#include<stddef.h>' | grep stddef.h
```

which is equivalent to including the header `<stddef.h>` in an empty C file and running `gcc -E` on it.

The headers in `/usr/include/linux` are used to compile the C library (usually glibc on Linux). The [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Linux.html#Linux) says:

> The **linux**, **asm** and **asm-generic** directories are required to
>   compile programs using the GNU C Library; the other directories
>   describe interfaces to the kernel but are not required if not
>   compiling programs using those interfaces. You do not need to copy
>   kernel headers if you did not specify an alternate kernel header
>   source using ‘--with-headers’.

whereas the C library headers are usually placed by somewhere in `/usr/lib/`. On my ubuntu 15.04, the header `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h` is empty. But on my CentOS, it has:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_STDDEF_H
#define _LINUX_STDDEF_H

#undef NULL
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif

#endif
```

The bottom line is, this is NOT the `stddef.h` you are interested in and in general, you should not make any assumptions about the location of the standard header files.

Comment: does `- <<<` is a specific syntax for `gcc`, that is, it is not valid in shell

Comment: @zhy `-` is something gcc understands. It means "read input from standard input". OTOH, `<<<` is bash specific (which is the default shell on most Linux distros), called as "here strings". If `<<<` isn't available then you can write the same as: `echo '#include<stddef.h>' | gcc -E - | grep stddef.h`.

Comment: I understand now. `<<<` means a here string, `<<` is a here document. Thank you!